# Handling angularjs dialog box in webpage using selenium

Tags: angularjs, selenium

I have an angularjs webpage that prompts when I perform certain action on the page. The code should ignore and continue if there is no prompt, but if a prompt appears then ensure that the javascript prompt is accepted.

When I use firebug, I get the following property of the element.
    /html/body/div[2]

The div[number] changes as and when I go to this page.I am not able to use the same in XPath as everytime the test case is executed, the div element would change. Also the div has an attribute of **tabindex = -1**.

```
 bool status = false;
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        IWebElement alert;

        if (wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated((By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am in if loop");
            status = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I am in else loop");
            alert = Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body/div[2]"));
            ((IJavaScriptExecutor)webDriver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", alert);
            status = true;
        }

        return status;
```

How do I handle such a dialog box and ensure that the same is accepted when it appears.

Thanks.

[image: Image of the Angular JS dialog box]

Comment: First of all, please check if it's a modal window, alert, or a div? Based on them, the solution might change. For changing xpath, you can either use a `CSS` selector (recommended by Selenium) or use the `contains` method as mentioned in the answer below. Please add relevant HTML in question as it would make it easier to provide a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can derive the xpath using the title of the alert. May be like below. (I do not know the exact html, just imagining the header text is in some span tag)

`alert = Browser.Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("/html/body//div/span[contains(text(),'Apply changes to controller configuration')]"));`

`(//)` can avoid using index to your div tag.

Comment: How do you know it's an alert and not a modal window? Or a separate div?